# Rails include form in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a rails app (a jobs board site) with a Job Model, Controller and Views (index/show). I've included an apply_to_email:string in my model which is connected to a button ("Apply" in the job post / show view). I am trying to create a contact form for this (called "Apply") with a separate controller, view and model. See below. How can I make the form below available in the Jobs Show page and have the message sent include information about the job post? I need the form to send to the apply_to_email. I'm thinking the end result should look something like www.example.com/jobs/job-post-title/apply (displays the contact form below).

Thanks a lot in advance!

apply.rb

```
class Apply < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message,   :validate => true
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  def headers
    {
        :subject => "Contact Form",
        :to => "example@example.com",
        :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
      }
  end
end
```

apply_controller.rb

```
class ApplyController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @apply = Apply.new
    end

    def create
        @apply = Apply.new(params[:apply])
        @apply.request = request
        if @apply.deliver
           flash.now[:error] = nil
        else
           flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send application.'
           render :new
        end
    end
end
```

apply/new.html.erb

```
<div class="apply-form">
    <%= form_for @apply do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name, required: true %>

        <br>

        <%= f.label :email %><br>
        <%= f.email_field :email, required: true %>

        <br>

        <%= f.label :message %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :message, as: :text %>

        <div class="hidden">
            <%= f.label :nickname %><br>
            <%= f.text_field :nickname, hint: 'leave this field blank' %>
        </div>

        <%= f.submit 'Send', class: "button" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

apply/create.html.erb

```
<div class="apply-success">
    <h1>Thank you for your application!</h1>
    <p>The employer will get back to you soon.</p>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :jobs
  resources :apply, only: [:new, :create]
  root 'landing#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `#render` method inside your `job/show.html.erb` to render a template from another controller. (In your case the ApplyController)

See `2.2.2 Rendering an Action's Template from Another Controller` from [the rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#usi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bng-render)

in your case, it would look like:

```
<%= render 'apply/new' %>
```